# Deriving boundary conditions for Faraday's law and Ampére's law by letting the width $\delta$ approach zero

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, stokes-theorem

I am currently studying the textbook *Physics of Photonic Devices*, second edition, by Shun Lien Chuang. Section **2.1.1 Maxwell's Equations in MKS Units** says the following:

> The well-known Maxwell's equations in MKS (meter, kilogram, and second) units are written as
> $$\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = - \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{t}}\mathbf{B} \ \ \ \ \text{Faraday's law} \tag{2.1.1}$$
> $$\nabla \times \mathbf{H} = \mathbf{J} + \dfrac{\partial{\mathbf{D}}}{\partial{t}} \ \ \ \ \text{Ampére's law} \tag{2.1.2}$$
> $$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{D} = \rho \ \ \ \ \text{Gauss's law} \tag{2.1.3}$$
> $$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} = 0 \ \ \ \ \text{Gauss's law} \tag{2.1.4}$$
> where $\mathbf{E}$ is the electric field (V/m), $\mathbf{H}$ is the magnetic field (A/m), $\mathbf{D}$ is the electric displacement flux density (C/m$^2$), and $\mathbf{B}$ is the magnetic flux density (Vs/m$^2$ or Webers/m$^2$). The two source terms, the charge density $\rho$ (C/m$^3$) and the current density $\mathbf{J}$ (A/m$^2$), are related by the continuity equation
> $$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{J} + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{t}} \rho = 0 \tag{2.1.5}$$

Section **2.1.2 Boundary Conditions** then says the following:

> By applying the first two Maxwell's equations over a small rectangular surface with a width $\delta$ (dashed line in Fig. 2.1a) across the interface of a boundary and using Stokes' theorem between a line integral over a contour $C$ and the surface $S$ enclosed by the contour
> $$\oint_C \mathbf{E} \cdot d \mathscr{l} = \int_S \nabla \times \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ dS = - \dfrac{d}{dt} \int_S \mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ dS \tag{2.1.9a}$$
> $$\oint_C \mathbf{H} \cdot d \mathscr{l} = \int_S \nabla \times \mathbf{H} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ dS = \int_S \mathbf{J} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ dS + \dfrac{d}{dt} \int_S \mathbf{D} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ dS, \tag{2.1.9b}$$
> the following boundary conditions can be derived by letting the width $\delta$ approach zero:
> $$\mathbf{\hat{n}} \times (\mathbf{E}_1 - \mathbf{E}_2) = 0 \tag{2.1.10}$$
> $$\mathbf{\hat{n}} \times (\mathbf{H}_1 - \mathbf{H}_2) = \mathbf{J}_s, \tag{2.1.11}$$
> where $\mathbf{J}_s(= \lim\limits_{\mathbf{J} \to \infty, \ \delta \to 0} \mathbf{J} \delta)$ is the surface current density (A/m). Note that the unit normal vector $\hat{n}$ points from medium 2 to medium 1.
> [image]

How does letting $\delta$ approach zero get us 2.1.10 and 2.1.11? And why do we have $\mathbf{E}_1 - \mathbf{E}_2$ and $\mathbf{H}_1 - \mathbf{H}_2$ instead of $\mathbf{E}_2 - \mathbf{E}_1$ and $\mathbf{H}_2 - \mathbf{H}_1$?

Comment: For anyone who's interested, this is also posted on the [physics site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/683821).

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin That's a completely different question. Or are you just saying it's related?

Comment: These are all the same boundary conditions. The electric half of Eq.2.1.14  is the same as Eq.2.1.10,  and Eq.2.1.15 is taking $\mathbf{H}_2=0$ as a perfect conductor in Eq.2.1.11$~~.\qquad$ The answerer there Michael Seifert also told you that.